# DynamicJasper missing test folder when adding it with gradle dependency manager

Tags: dynamic-jasper

i have a problem with dynamic-Jasper.
when i add dynamic-Jasper to my project with gradle using like:
compile group: 'ar.com.fdvs', name: 'DynamicJasper', version: '5.0.10'

the downloaded library has not test folder so i get : cannot resolve ar.com.fdvs.dj.test.ReportExporter;
because it cannot find dj.test and there is no such folder.
I tried different versions and feven I've downloaded the jar file manually but it is the same.
how do I add this library to get the full package?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ReportExporter** is for testing purposes only (since it is not a general purpose tool) and is not part of the main jar artifact. If you need something like **ReportExporter**, just [copy the file](https://github.com/FDVSolutions/DynamicJasper/blob/master/src/test/java/ar/com/fdvs/dj/test/ReportExporter.java), add it to your project and edit it to your needs.

Regards